# Not able to access my webcam using opencv library

Tags: qt, opencv, camera, webcam

I'm trying to use my webcam (in Qt) using OpenCv library. I get an error for this code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QImage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cv::VideoCapture camera;
   camera.open(1);
}
```

saying

```
/home/darshan/AindraDesktopApp/main.cpp:27: error: undefined reference to  `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
/home/darshan/AindraDesktopApp/main.cpp:28: error: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(int)'
/home/darshan/AindraDesktopApp/main.cpp:30: error: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/home/darshan/AindraDesktopApp/main.cpp:30: error: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
collect2: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you include the opencv2 header files? Please post the source for you `main` file. (Shorten it to only the relevant parts, please.)

Comment: You have to add the linking libraries.

Comment: I've added the linking libraries.